# Show Python virtualenv name and a short path in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, conda, virtualenv

I want to simplify my powershell prompt when using Python virtual environment: I want to see the name of the current environment, and the current directory only (not the full path).

For example, I want to convert this

```bash
(venv) PS C:User\me\Desktop\project\subfolder>
```

to this:

```bash
(venv) PS subfolder>
```

I tried many Powershell profile.ps configuration, such as

```bash
function prompt {
  $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
  "$p> "
}
```

But this command hides the current virtual environment.

Does someone already achieved to do what I want ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Oh My Posh and the [Python segment](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/segments/python).

Answer (score 0):

First I use this command to get the default config:

```
(Get-Command Prompt).ScriptBlock
```

In my computer I got this:

```
if ($Env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER) {
    $conda = $Env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER | Write-Host -NoNewline
}
```

Finally use in my Powershell profile.ps:

```
function prompt {
   $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)  
   if ($Env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER) {
      $conda = $Env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER | Write-Host -NoNewline
   }
   "$conda$p> "
 }
```